# Time operations in Java

Tags: java, time

I wonder that is there any way to perform time operations more special and except from **System.currentTimeMillis()**  and **System.nanoTime()** ? It can be dependent JVM.

Comment: Please be more specific. What kind of time operations you want to perform?

Comment: Java 8 has support for `System.picoTime()` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There is another Class  to perform timing and delay operations in multithreading environment. That is.

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
```